# entropy of an encrypted image after scrambling

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encryption

i have an algorithm called the arnold 2-D map that just permutes the pixels of the image and doesn't change the vlaues of the pixels.
but when i calculate the entropy values of the main image and the encrypted version the values are coming to be different. I am not able to understand this because since the formula for entropy just involves the probability of a pixel value in the image and that remains same after applying the cat map ,so why should the entropy change.
Can somebody help

Comment: What program/function are you using to calculate the entropy?

Comment: E=entropy(image)

Comment: Verify the class (type) of main image and encrypted version is the same. `entropy(double(I))`, `entropy(uint16(I))` and `entropy(uint8(I))` gives different result.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look inside the matlab function entropy:

```
edit entropy
```

->

```
I = im2uint8(I);

p = imhist(I(:));

% remove zero entries in p 
p(p==0) = [];

% normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
p = p ./ numel(I);

E = -sum(p.*log2(p));
```

So it calculates the entropy based on the histogram of the image. All the spatial data is lost. You are right, the entropy should not change at all in any transform which does not affect the intensity values. Also note that the data type is changed to uint8 before calculating the entropy, so any possible floating point errors etc. should be truncated.

That leaves the Arnold map. I'd suggest you take a look at it, there's probably a bug, image overflow or lost pixels somewhere.

Comment: but everything else is right when i calcaulate histograms of the two images it results in being same ,when i compare the images they are same,but when i view the histogram in matlab it is different and also the entropy is different

Comment: Check out the raw result data. A lot can be hidden inside a histogram bin.

Comment: raw result? i didn't understand

Comment: The data that your program outputs, before you bin it and turn it into a histogram. Even though the histograms look identical in the original program there might be a difference between the intensities of the two permuted images that are hidden by the binning.

Comment: there is no dfference in the values

Comment: Hmm. Are you saving the image at any point? Compression artifacts could be one explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139013/discussion-between-tapio-and-upstart).